# Using canvas graphics instead of traditional sprites in phaser

Tags: javascript, sprites, html-canvas, phaser

I'm trying to learn Phaser (total beginner with mild JS experience) and I'm following tutorials and such where everything is using sprites. I'm trying to get by with basic canvas shapes instead of creating sprites, but I'm having trouble implementing them in some situations.

I have a working player shape:

```
var playerGraphic = this.game.add.graphics(100, 100);

// set a fill and line style
playerGraphic.beginFill(0x555555);
playerGraphic.lineStyle(2, 0xffffff, 0.5);

// draw a shape
playerGraphic.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
playerGraphic.drawCircle(5, 5, 10);

this.player = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY, null);

this.player.addChild(playerGraphic);
```

But I'm unsure if this is the correct way of doing it.

I'm also struggling to get a tiled background to work, as it doesn't seem to work in the same way as above:

```
this.game.background = this.game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, this.game.world.width, this.game.world.height, null);

this.game.background.addChild(bgGraphic);
```

Any advice/help?

Comment: did you find out if this is the right way? or is there another solution to it?